# Text Blob for finding polarity of sentence

Tags: python-3.x

I am using TextBlob for finding polarity of sentence but i am facing following problems

```
>>> from textblob import TextBlob
>>> blob = TextBlob("I am listening amazing music", classifier=cl)
>>> blob.classify()
```

when i enter these in python console it gives name 'cl' not defined.Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You should define the classifier before you use it.

Here is the example from the [Textblob API Reference](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/api_reference.html#module-textblob.classifiers) , please read it or read the tutorial before you try this module.

```
>>> from textblob import TextBlob
>>> from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
>>> train = [
...     ('I love this sandwich.', 'pos'),
...     ('This is an amazing place!', 'pos'),
...     ('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'),
...     ('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'),
...     ('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'),
...     ("I can't deal with this", 'neg'),
...     ("My boss is horrible.", "neg")
... ]
>>> cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
>>> cl.classify("I feel amazing!")
'pos'
>>> blob = TextBlob("The beer is good. But the hangover is horrible.", classifier=cl)
>>> for s in blob.sentences:
...     print(s)
...     print(s.classify())
...
The beer is good.
pos
But the hangover is horrible.
neg
```